# Sharing Data Between Angular 7 Components

Tags: css, angular, output, eventemitter, pass-data

I would like to send data from the `age` input from `child-information` component to the `age-line`, component which includes a vertical line. This line moves left `'age * 100 pixels'` when it gets the age.

What's wrong with my code? There are no error messages.

Child-inf.html:

```
 <button id="okButton" (click)=addAge()>OK</button>
 Age : <input 
 type="text" name="Age" value="Kor" id="ageId" onfocus="this.value = 
 this.value=='Kor'?'':this.value;" onblur="this.value = 
 this.value==''?'Kor':this.value;">
```

Child-inf.ts:

```
export class ChildInformationsComponent implements OnInit {
 age:number = 1;
  @Output() buttonClicked: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  addAge(){
    this.age =parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('ageId')).value);
    this.buttonClicked.emit(this.age); 
  }
}
```

Age line html:

```
 <div class="age-line" [style.left.px]="age * 100"> <div class="line"></div> </div>
```

Age line ts:

```
export class AgeLineComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() { }
 age: number= 1;


 showNextComponent(emittedAge: number) {
   this.age = emittedAge;
   console.log('Button clicked');
 }

 ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Comment: Age line doesn't have a property `(buttonClicked)`, it exists on Child-inf

Comment: post the parent html containing age line and child selectors

Comment: bro 0 * n = 0. So initialize age: number = 1

Comment: still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you use [Output()](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) when you need to emit a value from a Child Component to his Parent in Child-Parent relationship.

I don't see that the `Age line` Component has as a child the `Child-inf`.

If you want that `Child-inf` and `Age line` has a Child-Parent relationship, you should include the `Child-inf` in the `Age line` Html.

**Age line html:**

```
<div class="age-line" [style.left.px]="age * 100"> <div class="line"></div> </div>
<child-inf></child-inf>
```

Here I asume that the `Child-inf` Component selector is:`child-inf`

Then if you want to listen to the Output Event in the `Child-inf` Component, in the  `Age line` html you have to do:

**Age line html:**

```
<div class="age-line" [style.left.px]="age * 100"> <div class="line"></div> </div>
<child-inf (buttonClicked)="showNextComponent($event)"></child-inf>
```

Comment: Ok. Let see this: ```Age : <input (buttonClicked)='showNextComponent($event)'``` why do you have the (buttonClicked) in the input of the child-inf? You shouldn't please remove it. 
Also, do you try yo see if the addAge la being fired and if you see getting the vale of the input?

Comment: I removed buttonClicked from age input of course after your advice, but still not working :(

Comment: I would prefer if you can upload the code or part of the code to https://stackblitz.com/ because in that case all the users that see this question would see the current issue and the solution when we reach it

Comment: Great, only one comment, you forget to add the app.module

Comment: Done, let me know if its ok

Comment: I have the following errors:

Import error, can't find files:
./app-routing.module
./app.component
./activity/activity.component
./category/category.component
./child-informations/child-informations.component
./parent-informations/parent-informations.component
./age-line/age-line.component

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your missing the child component from **Age Line HTML**

Your outputting buttonClicked, so your code would need to look something like this.

**Age Line HTML:**

```
<div class="age-line" [style.left.px]="age * 100"> <div class="line"></div> </div>
<child-inf (buttonClicked)="showNextComponent($event)"></child-inf>
```

Now when you emit to **buttonClicked**, the **showNextComponent** method will fire.

You should also extend **Child-inf.ts** from **AgeLine.ts**.

```
export class ChildInformationsComponent extends AgeLineComponent{
    // Methods and stuff
}
```